# Billing of managed disk with arbitrary disk size

Tags: azure

In their [managed disk pricing page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/managed-disks/), Microsoft Azure present a billing method based on predefined disk size, but nowhere do thy mention pricing of arbitrary disk size. I would assume they charge by the closest larger disk size (e.g a 38GiB will be charged as 64GiB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct. When considering the disk size for billing of the managed disk. You can refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/managed-disks-overview#pricing-and-billing).

> Billing for managed disks depends on the provisioned size
>   of the disk. Azure maps the provisioned size (rounded up) to the
>   nearest Managed Disks option as specified in the tables below. Each
>   managed disk maps to one of the supported provisioned sizes and is
>   billed accordingly. For example, if you create a standard managed disk
>   and specify a provisioned size of 200 GB, you are billed as per the
>   pricing of the S15 Disk type.

[image]